# Vaadin: open calendar on field focus for datefield

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

Vaadin widgets are simple and awesome! But they are also poorly configurable. 
I need my DateField widget to open calendar on focus event. I didn't find that functionality in official [Vaadin documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-datefield.html). I found some 3rd party widget [here](https://github.com/fdreyfs/vaadin-tuning-datefield), but it's compiled for Vaadin 7.7 and I use latest Vaadin (8.0.6). Also it has Joda-time 2.1 dependency which is highly undesirable in my project. So, is there any simple way to tune stock vaadin DateField widget to open it's calendar on field focus, or do I need to write my own component for that? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, perhaps you could share a [sscce](http://sscce.org) with some more details? For example, using Vaadin 8.0.6, if I create a `DateField` with a date somewhere in the past (eg `addComponent(new DateField("Event date", LocalDate.of(2011, Month.FEBRUARY, 6)))`) and click its calendar icon, it will popup with that particular page and date...

Comment: @Morfic I want to open calendar popup not only by clicking the calendar button, but also by focusing to a field itself.

Comment: It's clearer now, initially I misunderstood that you wanted to open the popup _focusing the selected event date_. Unfortunately, afaik so far, there's no simple way to programmatically open these popups, eg: calendar date selection, grid editor, combo items. Potentially you could add a [javascript extension](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/gwt/gwt-javascript.html) to click the button on focus. I'll try to wrap up a simple example to get you started...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I was saying in my comment, as far as I know, currently the framework does not offer an implicit way to programmatically open the calendar popup. The same thing goes for some other components such as the grid editor, or the combo item list.

One quick workaround I can think of, is to add a [javascript extension](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/gwt/gwt-javascript.html) that registers focus listeners for all date fields, and clicks the button when a date field is focused. Please find below a sample.

P.S. If you only need to apply this to only some date fields, you can add IDs and pass them to the JS, where you'll do something like `document.getElementById('myDateFieldId')` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName("v-datefield")`.

**1) Layout with components**

```java
public class MyDateFieldComponent extends HorizontalLayout {
    public MyDateFieldComponent() {
        // basic setup
        DateField fromDateField = new DateField("From", LocalDate.of(2011, Month.FEBRUARY, 6));
        DateField toDateField = new DateField("To", LocalDate.of(2018, Month.FEBRUARY, 6));
        setSpacing(true);
        addComponents(fromDateField, toDateField);

        // add the extension
        addExtension(new CalendarFocusPopupOpenerExtension());
    }
}
```

**2) Extension - java/server side**

```java
import com.vaadin.annotations.JavaScript;
import com.vaadin.server.AbstractJavaScriptExtension;

@JavaScript("calendar-focus-popup-opener-extension.js")
public class CalendarFocusPopupOpenerExtension extends AbstractJavaScriptExtension {
    public CalendarFocusPopupOpenerExtension() {
        // call the bind function defined in the associated JS
        callFunction("bind");
    }
}
```

**3) Extension - js/client side**

```js
window.com_example_calendar_CalendarFocusPopupOpenerExtension = function () {
    this.bind = function () {
        if (document.readyState === "complete") {
            // if executed when document already loaded, just bind
            console.log("Doc already loaded, binding");
            bindToAllDateFields();
        } else {
            // otherwise, bind when finished loading
            console.log("Doc nod loaded, binding later");
            window.onload = function () {
                console.log("Doc finally loaded, binding");
                bindToAllDateFields();
            }
        }
    };

    function bindToAllDateFields() {
        // get all the date fields to assign focus handlers to
        var dateFields = document.getElementsByClassName("v-datefield");
        for (var i = 0; i < dateFields.length; i++) {
            addFocusListeners(dateFields[i]);
        }
    }

    function addFocusListeners(dateField) {
        // when focusing the date field, click the button
        dateField.onfocus = function () {
            dateField.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].click();
        };

        // or when focusing the date field input, click the button
        dateField.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].onfocus = function () {
            dateField.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].click();
        };
    }
};
```

**4) Result**
[image: Calendar popup open on focus]

---

### **LATER UPDATE**

A second approach could be to assign some IDs to your fields, and then check periodically to see when all are visible, and as soon as they are, bind the focus listeners.

**1) Layout with components**

```java
public class MyDateFieldComponent extends HorizontalLayout {
    public MyDateFieldComponent() {
        // basic setup
        DateField fromDateField = new DateField("From", LocalDate.of(2011, Month.FEBRUARY, 6));
        fromDateField.setId("fromDateField"); // use id to bind
        fromDateField.setVisible(false); // initially hide it

        DateField toDateField = new DateField("To", LocalDate.of(2018, Month.FEBRUARY, 6));
        toDateField.setId("toDateField"); // use id to bind
        toDateField.setVisible(false); // initially hide it

        // simulate a delay until the fields are available
        Button showFieldsButton = new Button("Show fields", e -> {
            fromDateField.setVisible(true);
            toDateField.setVisible(true);
        });

        setSpacing(true);
        addComponents(showFieldsButton, fromDateField, toDateField);

        // add the extension
        addExtension(new CalendarFocusPopupOpenerExtension(fromDateField.getId(), toDateField.getId()));
    }
}
```

**2) Extension - java/server side**

```java
@JavaScript("calendar-focus-popup-opener-extension.js")
public class CalendarFocusPopupOpenerExtension extends AbstractJavaScriptExtension {
    public CalendarFocusPopupOpenerExtension(String... idsToBindTo) {
        // send the arguments as an array of strings
        JsonArray arguments = Json.createArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < idsToBindTo.length; i++) {
            arguments.set(i, idsToBindTo[i]);
        }

        // call the bind defined in the associated JS
        callFunction("bind", arguments);
    }
}
```

**3) Extension - js/client side**

```js
window.com_example_calendar_CalendarFocusPopupOpenerExtension = function () {
    var timer;

    this.bind = function (idsToBindTo) {
        // check every second to see if the fields are available. interval can be tweaked as required
        timer = setInterval(function () {
            bindWhenFieldsAreAvailable(idsToBindTo);
        }, 1000);
    };

    function bindWhenFieldsAreAvailable(idsToBindTo) {
        console.log("Looking for the following date field ids: [" + idsToBindTo + "]");
        var dateFields = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < idsToBindTo.length; i++) {
            var dateFieldId = idsToBindTo[i];
            var dateField = document.getElementById(dateFieldId);
            if (!dateField) {
                // field not present, wait
                console.log("Date field with id [" + dateFieldId + "] not found, sleeping");
                return;
            } else {
                // field present, add it to the list
                console.log("Date field with id [" + dateFieldId + "] found, adding to binding list");
                dateFields.push(dateField);
            }
        }

        // all fields present and accounted for, bind the listeners!
        clearInterval(timer);
        console.log("All fields available, binding focus listeners");
        bindTo(dateFields);
    }

    function bindTo(dateFields) {
        // assign focus handlers to all date fields
        for (var i = 0; i < dateFields.length; i++) {
            addFocusListeners(dateFields[i]);
        }
    }

    function addFocusListeners(dateField) {
        // when focusing the date field, click the button
        dateField.onfocus = function () {
            dateField.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].click();
        };

        // or when focusing the date field input, click the button
        dateField.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].onfocus = function () {
            dateField.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].click();
        };
    }
};
```

**4) Result**[image: Calendar popup open on focus]

Comment: Looks cool, but I have a trouble with your code: function `bindToAllDateFields` is called before datefield is rendered. How can I call this function after page load?

Comment: @Everv0id I changed the name of the initial function to `bind` and added a check to see if the doc is already loaded when it's called. If it is, then it will bind immediately, otherwise it will use an `onload` function to bind. Your UI is probably more complex so it finishes at a later time, but in my case when it was executed, the doc was loaded. You can check the developer console (chrome, firefox, etc) so see the log lines I added (obviously you can also remove them before committing your code, they're just for debugging purpose).

Comment: thank you, unfortunately the result is the same. I tried to debug js code and found that `document.readyState === "complete"` is true when the function `bind` is called, but there are no `.v-datefield` elements on page at the moment. On my page I use Grid with some time filters, and when `bind` is called, none of filters and rows are rendered.

Comment: @Everv0id hmm, strange, I must be missing something... what if you try removing the `if` and just use `window.onload`, eg `window.onload = function() {bindToAllDateFields();}`

Comment: Also, I've just created feature request about this on Vaadin github page: https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/9528

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt help too. Looks like grid contents (and even filters in header) are loaded asynchronously after document is loaded. When `bind` is called, document is already has the state `complete`, and `window.onload` assignment gives no effect. Sad :(

Comment: @Everv0id hmm, if you load some data in a background thread, perhaps instead of calling `bind` in the constructor of `CalendarFocusPopupOpenerExtension`, you can move it to a method and call it when the loading is done. Given your situation, perhaps you can also share a [sscce](http://sscce.org) to easily debug your scenario.

Comment: how can i track that loading is done? Didn't find any signs of this at `Grid` page on Vaadin docs.

Comment: @Everv0id I was thinking of calling it after the call to `myService.loadData(myFilter)` or whatever it is that's loading your data. Nonetheless, single page applications make it tricky to work with `windows.onload` (or similar checks) and so far I don't know of any event triggered by Vaadin (there's an [issue](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/1317) open for that), so we try working around the problem. That's why I was asking for a [sscce](http://sscce.org) to easily reproduce it, and figure if there are any solutions, like a timeout, or checking for a _final element_ in the dom

Comment: @Everv0id I've added a second possible workaround, based on periodically checking that all your expected fields (identified by their IDs) are available, and bind the focus listeners once they are. If this does not work either, I can't think of anything else without having a [sscce](http://sscce.org) to work with.